# When extending an interface, should we use object keyword?

Tags: object, kotlin, interface

I have two different pieces of code. In one i need to use *object* and in the second i'm not.
Can someone explain me the difference between the situation:
first Code:

```
   private val onInitWebResponseHandler: VolleyHandler.WebResponseHandler = VolleyHandler.WebResponseHandler()
{
    Thread(ParseJsonStringOnInit(WeakReference(this),
            weakRefIOnAllScoresDataFirstFetched, it)).start()

}
```

Second Code:

```
val competitionOrderLevelComparator : Comparator<CompetitionObj> = object : Comparator<CompetitionObj> {
    override fun compare(object1: CompetitionObj, object2: CompetitionObj): Int
    {
        return object1.orderLevel - object2.orderLevel
    }

}


      fun interface  WebResponseHandler
{
    fun onWebResponseFinished(jsonString:String?)
}
```

In addition how the first code, we can have **()** brackets if interface doesn't have a constructor?

Comment: This should explain it: [how-to-create-an-instance-of-anonymous-interface-in-kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37672023/how-to-create-an-instance-of-anonymous-interface-in-kotlin) and [cant-understand-how-to-use-sam-interface-in-kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64793715/cant-understand-how-to-use-sam-interface-in-kotlin)

Comment: @ChristianB, thanks!!! but can you explain how the **()** works in the first example:`VolleyHandler.WebResponseHandler()` since it's an interface

Comment: Can you show the definition of `VolleyHandler.WebResponseHandler` ?

Comment: @Animesh Sahu, correct me if I am wrong, then `VolleyHandler.WebResponseHandler` can't be an interface, as @Eitanos30 is able calling a constructor on it. A SAM would called (without constructor) like `SamInterface { ... }`

Comment: @ChristianB, i have added the `VolleyHandler.WebResponseHandler`

Comment: If i'm putting the first `{` immediately after `VolleyHandler.WebResponseHandler` (at the same line of code) i don't need the `()`, **but** if i put the open `{` one line below `VolleyHandler.WebResponseHandler`, then i must add the `()`

Comment: @ChristianB SAM-converted lambdas have an optional empty constructor you can call, which is necessary if you open the brackets on the next line.